# Android Studio : Is the fabric moved from jcenter to some other location(maven)

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, crashlytics, google-fabric

Why I am not able to get the Fabric downloaded from within the Android Studio .

```
I am using AS 3.2
Gradle Version : 4.6
Android Plugin : 3.2.0
```

Below is my build script :

```
buildscript {
                repositories {
                    jcenter() {

        }
        google()
        maven {url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public'  }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.0'
        classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'

    }
}



allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter() {

        }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
    }
}
```

But I am getting 407 issues :

```
> Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
      > Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'. Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required
      > Failed to list versions for io.fabric.tools:gradle.
         > Unable to load Maven meta-data from https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.
            > Could not get resource 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
               > Could not GET 'https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml'.
```

https://jcenter.bintray.com/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.>> doesnt open

https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.>> gives 404 Error

https://maven.fabric.io/public/io/fabric/tools/gradle/maven-metadata.xml.>>
gives the atatched Image

[image]

I am behind the Proxy and able to download sdk and Build tools.

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving a proxy error:

`Received status code 407 from server: Proxy Authentication Required`

You can configure gradle to authenticate at the proxy by setting some properties at the `gradle.properties` file:

Configuring an HTTP proxy using gradle.properties

```
systemProp.http.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.http.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.http.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.http.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.http.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

There are separate settings for HTTPS.
Configuring an HTTPS proxy using gradle.properties

```
systemProp.https.proxyHost=www.somehost.org
systemProp.https.proxyPort=8080
systemProp.https.proxyUser=userid
systemProp.https.proxyPassword=password
systemProp.https.nonProxyHosts=*.nonproxyrepos.com|localhost
```

For more information, please visit: https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/build_environment.html#sec:accessing_the_web_via_a_proxy

Comment: This is fine, but which is the correct URL for the fabric? I see only maven responded.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, especially in corporate environments, one might need to add the corporate repository to the repository configuration.

```
repositories {
    maven {
        url "http://corp.repository.net/libs"
    }
    jcenter()
    google()
}
```